# Jquery fade in images one by one, in reverse

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am using the below code to fade in each image 1 by 1. How could I do this in revers so the images load in the opposite order?

```
  img {display:none;}
  $('img').each(function(i) {
      $(this).delay(i * 100).fadeIn();
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a normal for loop and just decrement

```
for(var count = $('img').length-1; count >= 0; count--)
{
    $('img:eq('+count+')').fadeIn();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This would be fine

```
$($('img').get().reverse()).each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(i * 100).fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how many images you have but you can do it individually.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("button").click(function(){
     $("#div1").fadeIn("1000");
     $("#div2").fadeIn("2000");
     $("#div3").fadeIn(3000);
     });
```

Although for loads of images I would wait

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reverse()`. However be aware that if your images have a style `display:none` and floated they will take no space. This means when they fadeIn in reverse order they will "jump" and cause a flickering effect. I recommend using `visibility: hidden` so the images take space while they are not visible.

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/eqE9J/154/)

jquery

```
  $($("img").get().reverse()).each(function(i) {
      $(this).css('visibility','visible').hide().delay(i * 100).fadeIn();
  });
```

css

```
img{
    max-width:30%;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```